# Send buffer of 288 Uint16 values from One arduino to another using SPI

Tags: arduino, buffer, spi

I am trying to send a buffer of 288 Uint16 values from one Arduino (the main) to a secondary Arduino using SPI between the two. I am trying to send over a buffer of data and then read it on the secondary Arduino and serial print the buffer that I received but I seem to get random values (every time it serial prints they are different values from the buffer). Not sure if it is splitting the uint16 into to separate bytes when it sends over or if I am not reading or writing the SPI values correctly. Is there a way to send over an array of 16 bit values all at once with SPI and then read into a buffer on the second Arduino? I am new to SPI on Arduino so any advice would be helpful.

*Primary Arduino Code:*

```
#include<SPI.h>

uint16_t buffer_data[288];


void setup()
{
  pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV32);  //2^n = 2, 4, 8, 16, 32

}


void loop()
{
digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
  for (uint16_t x = 0; x <sizeof(buffer_data); x++) {
    buffer_data[x] = x;
  }
  SPI.transfer(buffer_data, 288);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  delay(10000);
}
```

Secondary Arduino:

```
#include<SPI.h>

uint16_t buffer_new[288];
int pos = 0;
bool flag = false;

void setup()

{
  Serial.begin(115200);              

  SPCR |= _BV(SPE);                 

  SPI.attachInterrupt();                  
  
}

ISR (SPI_STC_vect)                        
{
  volatile byte data_new = SPDR;           
  
  if (pos < sizeof(buffer_new)) {   
    buffer_new[pos++]  = uint16_t(data_new);
    
  }
  else {
    flag = true;
  }
}

void loop()
{  
  if (flag) {
    for (int x = 0; x <288; x++) {
      Serial.println(buffer_new[x]);
    }
    pos = 0;
    flag = false;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
1
0
2
0
3
0
4
0
5
0
6
0
7
0
8
0
9
0
10
0
11
0
12
0
13
0
14
0
15
0
16
0
16
1
32
1
48
1
64
1
80
1
96
1
112
1
128
1
144
1
160
1
176
1
192
1
208
1
224
1
240
2
0
2
16
16
1
24
1
32
1
40
1
48
1
56
1
64
1
72
1
80
1
88
1
96
1
64
11
128
11
192
12
0
12
64
12
128
12
192
13
0
13
64
13
128
13
192
0
7
32
7
64
7
96
7
128
7
160
7
192
7
224
8
0
8
32
8
64
8
96
8
128
8
160
8
192
8
224
9
0
36
1
40
1
44
1
48
1
52
1
56
1
60
1
64
1
68
1
72
1
76
1
64
5
80
5
96
5
112
5
128
5
144
5
160
5
176
5
192
5
208
5
224
5
240
6
0
6
16
6
32
6
48
6
64
6
80
6
96
6
112
6
128
6
144
6
160
6
176
6
192
6
208
6
224
6
240
7
0
7
16
7
32
7
48
7
64
7
80
7
96
7
112
7
128
7
144
7
160
7
96
15
128
15
160
15
192
15
224
16
0
16
32
16
64
16
96
16
128
16
160
16
0
67
128
68
0
68
128
69
0
69
128
70
0
70
128
71
0
71
128
72
0
72
128
```

Comment: You could take a look at the examples on the Arduino official [website](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/SPI) (bottom of the page).

Comment: The transfer operates on abyte buffer and takes a length in bytes. It's unclear why you're filling a buffer of 288 `uint_16` values (which is 576 bytes) and then sending 288 bytes. Additionally, your sender loops on sending the entire buffer over and over, but your receiver receives once and stops. So it's unclear how you are getting sender and receiver synchronized. Once synchronized at the start, if you still get different results each time, check your connection for reliability.